# Remove hidden div tag from WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I installed a third party theme in WordPress. There is `div` tag inside my page that write "All for Joomla All for Webmasters", and when I click on it, it redirects to http://all4share.net.
already searched all CSS and PHP code for that string, but can't find it to remove from my page.

Comment: Are you using a pirated theme?

Comment: @RRikesh some how yes

Comment: Then it's probably in some encoded/hidden format. Probably look for `base64_encode()` function. Warning: I would not recommend you to use such themes, they may host malware/backdoors and you won't get updates if the theme has vulnerabilities.

Comment: give theme name or url so any one can check issue.

Comment: @RRikesh Right,person may be use demo version or null theme

Comment: @RR this is my site http://nikancharter.com/ , drag horizontal scrollbar to the left and you will see the link on top left side!